# Different approaches to ZF

Tags: set-theory

In Suppes book he starts with the conditional definition:
$y$ is a set $\iff ((\exists x)(x\in y)\lor y=\emptyset)$.

I.e. it is assumed that the empty set exists.

From there he defines the empty set:
$y=\emptyset \iff \neg(\exists x) (x\in y)$

And a theorem is proved that $y=\emptyset\iff \neg(\exists x)(x\in y)$.
This of course does not negate the existence of urelements ("individuals"), while in ZF no urelements exist.

So from what I understand his definition is a "cooky cutter" style.
After which you have to prove that the empty set exists.

Enderton on the otherhand gives the empty set axiom:
$(\forall x)(\exists y)(x\notin y)$.
This plus extensionality+aussonderung+pairing+sum axiom×...
allows sets to be defined.

My question is:

Are both approaches equivalent?

Can one prove the empty set axiom from Suppes conditional definition and theorem and vice versa?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the formulas correctly? Usually your first paragraph would be the condition for $x$ to be a set. And I think the quantifiers should be switched in Enderton’s empty set axiom.

Comment: I just checked my copy of Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, and as I thought he gives the empty set axiom as $\exists B\;\forall x\;x\not\in B$. I don't have a copy of Suppes.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where you mention that Suppes allows for urelements (aka atoms). That explains your first paragraph. People sometimes write ZFU (or ZFA) for the variation on ZF where urlements are allowed.  ZFU is not equivalent to ZF. But if you add in an axiom excluding urelements, then you get equivalent theories.